# Change font style in gridcontrol devexpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

how can i make italic font based on ISVERIFIKASI value?? if ISVERIFIKASI value is 1 make it all row font to italic and if it is 0 make it to default regular...

[image: this is my form]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [GridView.RowStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowStyletopic) event.

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
//...
void gridView_RowStyle(object sender, RowStyleEventArgs e) {
   GridView view = sender as GridView;
   if(e.RowHandle >= 0) {
      int value = (int)view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns["ISVERIFIKASI"]);
      if(value == 1) 
         e.Appearance.Font = ...;
   }
}
```